# RCL with pages to use in MAUI app and Blazor server app .Net 8.0

Tags: c#, blazor, shared-libraries, maui, razor-pages

I want to create a Blazor server app and MAUI app both sharing same UI. I have done the following

1. Create a RCL (Razor class library) project
2. Create a MAUI project
3. Create a Blazor server app project
4. Link MAUI and Blazor server app projects to use RCL
5. Add namespace to `_Imports.razor` file
6. Add additional assemblies attribute
7. Create a weather page to RCL
8. Remove original weather page from both MAUI and server App

Now MAUI app shows the weather page without any issue. Server App on the other hand generated 404 error. Not able to get this work.

Components work fine but when it comes to pages it's not working in server app. I have uploaded to  https://github.com/udayakumarlm/CommonUI.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've set up the Router to see the library assembly, but `Weather` is a static SSR (static server-side rendering) page, not an Interactive page.

You need to add the additional assembly to the Razor middleware handler so it can see it.

```cs
app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode()
    .AddAdditionalAssemblies(new[] { typeof(RazorClassLibrary1.TestClass).Assembly });
```

Comment: I hope my edit is in line with what you meant by ssr. interesting topic to share components between MAUI-blazor hybrid and blazor server or wasm. will apply your answer in one of my test projects. after that most important is to completely decouple logic from ui since web doesn't have access to native apis as MAUI does.

Comment: @Cfun - no problem.  I'm putting together some resources to cover what is for many a very confusing topic.